# Async Await not awaiting for async method to occur

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I am building up a shopping website for a project. I currently am writing a loadcart method using javascript. Basically what happens is that I store my cart data in my session storage. If no shopping cart data is found in session storage I fetch from the database. I made the function an async function because my getshoppingcartDB function is an asynchronous method.

When there is no data in session storage, I expected my method to enter the if clause, fetch the data from the database and update the cart array. However, my cart array is still blank. I notice that the cart array is **ONLY** updated later as shown by the screenshot.

As such, Im a litte curious how the await function? I thought the await is supposed to wait for a response back first but it seems here that it is being executed asynchronously.

[image]

This is my load cart function

```
// Load cart
cart = [];
async function loadCart() {
    console.log("LOAD CART")
    var uname = document.getElementById("username").innerText
    uname = uname.trim();

    if (sessionStorage.getItem("shoppingCart") === null) {
        console.log("check null")
        const cartdata= await getshoppingcartDB(uname);
        cart = cartdata
    }else{
        cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));
        

    }
    
    return cart
    
    
}

loadCart().then(function(response){
    cart = response

})
```

This is my async function for retrieving data from the database

```
async function getshoppingcartDB(email) {

    let params = {
        "email": email
    };

    let query = Object.keys(params)
        .map(k => encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(params[k]))
        .join('&');

    let url = '/getcartdatabyemail?' + query;

    const response = await fetch(url);
    return response.json()

}
```

PS: I edited my function as per Mike's advice but stll doesnt seem to work?  I also cant seem to do a result = await loadCart().

Comment: [`await` does not "halt all execution"](https://mzl.la/321mAQ6), it _only_ halts the `async` function with the `await` instruction in it, and immediately hands control back to the JS scheduler, which will start running any code that isn't awaiting "whatever is awaiting". So your second console.log runs basically _immediately_ (your code calls `loadCart`, that function runs, hits `await`, and gets put on halt with the JS scheduler moving  on to the next instruction). If you want your console.log to kick in only once `loadCart` is done, `await` that call.

Comment: Hi @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I tried to edit it as per suggested but I still cant assign the cart array. Is there something im doing wrong?

Comment: try `return await response.json()`

Comment: Btw [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)  will help - `url + new URLSeachParams({ email })` can skip that whole `Object.keys(...).map(...).join(...)` bit

Comment: Just wanted to add something if it would help you.

fetch(url) returns an object with a promise definition in it (basically an async method with the method name json, that takes in no args). So when you call response.json(), it runs that method asynchronously, because it is an async method. This is a common style in javascript async / promises, where an async method resolve a new promise definition. It is referred to as chaining. 

Gotchyas : The response of a fetch(url) need not be an object, it could be an async method directly instead of an object,

Comment: ... however, the advantage of returning an object... is that the fetch can also return some other data as well. This data in a fetch request is usually all the header information on the response. You can get things like cookies, the status code, and status message here. But to get the actual result of the request, you must await on response.json()